# Does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^{1/n}<1\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\max\{ 1,a_k\}\right)^{1/n}=1 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the positive valued sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying the condition $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^{1/n}<1$$ Is it true that this implies $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\max\{ 1,a_k\}\right)^{1/n}=1 ?$$ Though I am really dubious about this one, I am finding it difficult to prove or disprove this. A possible idea that I have is that I can write $$\max\{1,a_k\}=1+b_k$$ where $b_k\ge 0$ and then possibly find a way to show that $b_k\to 0$ which would serve the purpose, but I am really having problem pursuing this idea. So any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be related to [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), or at least Cesaro means

Comment: Have you tried to consider $\alpha_k = \ln a_k$, and work with the corresponding (equivalent) statements? (Edit: this is related to @Omnomnomnom's idea -- essentially, working with sums is easier than with products)

Comment: By the comment of @Omnomnomnom just now, I think if I can show that the Cesaro sum of the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is $0$, I can prove the desired result. Is this idea correct?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay my idea was closer to Clement's suggestion

Comment: Ok, so taking $\alpha_k=\ln a_k$, the problem reduces to checking whether $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sigma_k<0\implies \lim_{k\to \infty}\tau_k=0$, where I am denoting the mean sequence of $\alpha_k$ by $\sigma_k$ and the mean sequence of $\ln \max\{1,a_k\}$ by $\tau_k$.

Comment: Following the idea above, you may try $\alpha_n = -0.2015 + (-1)^n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, Ok, in that case $\max\{1,a_k\}>1$. Ok, actually this came from the analysis of a dynamical system and I was trying to see if the sequence converges. So, maybe I should the put the condition as $<\infty$ instead of $=1$ for the desired limit.

Comment: Actually, letting $\alpha_n = -0.2015 + (-1)^n \sqrt{n}$ makes things worse since $ \sigma_n \to -0.2015$ while $ \tau_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee for the comments. They really cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above: faced with infinite products, working with logarithms (and thus the equivalent statements in terms of infinite *sums*) usually helps.

In this particular case, no matter how you build your intuition (e.g., as above or not), you may end up considering a counterexample such as
$a_{2n} = \frac{n}{3}$, $a_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{n}$.

You do have $$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^{1/n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{2}{3}$$ (e.g., by considering the two subsequences $(\prod_{k=1}^{2n+1} a_k)^{1/{2n+1}}$ and $(\prod_{k=1}^{2n} a_k)^{1/2n}$; but
$$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \max(1,a_k)\right)^{1/n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Comment: Yes @Clement C. I think the main problem is that we are ignoring all the "small" elements in the sequence $a_n$ which is giving off such large values.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Yes -- basically, you prevent any nice "cancellation" from happening.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. Then I think in place of $1$ if I put another sequence having property similar to $a_n$, it would work, right?

Comment: Not quite... take the counterexample I gave, but define $b_n$ by "switching" the even and odd indices (so that $b_{2n}=a_{2n+1}$ and vice-versa.) Taking the maximum termwise will result in a product going to infinity as well...

Comment: Yeah, right. Then it seems that I can always find examples of $b_n,a_n$ to have a counterexample. So do both the sequences $a_n,b_n$ need to be convergent? I think this oscillatory behavior is the real culprit here, right?

Comment: If you add the assumption that $(a_n)_n$ be bounded, then you can have the conclusion with $\leq M$ instead of $= 1$ -- would that be enough?

Comment: The problem is that the only available information about $a_n$ is the one I gave in the question. I do not even know if they are bounded.